# Arranging flex-items in a particular way

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'd like to arrange *flex-items* in the following manner:

[image: Layout]

Using the following example:

```css
.Container {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-top: -100px;
  padding-top: 100px;
  position: relative;
  width: 70vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="Top">Top Content</div>
<div class="Container">
  <div class="Left">Left Content</div>
  <div class="Middle">Middle Content</div>
  <div class="Right">Right Content</div>
</div>
```

I can make it so there is a horizontal bar and vertical columns under it. However, I cannot figure out how to make **another** vertical column; one consisting of the above code, and the other a different div.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the grid solution applicable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flex. For each "direction" use a container. To divide ratio 1:2 use `flex-grow: 1` and `flex-grow: 2;`.

It's also important to use

```
flex-shrink: 0;
flex-basis: 0;
```

if you want to keep the ratio regardless of the content inside, otherwise, the browser will resize the divs according to the content inside them.

There is a shorter way of writing all the 3:

```
flex: [flex-grow], [flex-shrink], [flex-basis];
```

but IE doesn't support it, so I prefer using the long way

```css
.out-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.inner-cont {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-grow: 2;
}

.container {
  flex-grow: 2;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 70vw;
}

.left,
.right,
.middle,
.top {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.left {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 0;
  background-color: #aaeffe;
}

.top {
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background-color: #69e2fd;
}

.middle{
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background-color: #38d0fd;
}

.right{
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background-color: #1fbbfb;
}
```

```html
<div class="out-container">
  <div class="left">Left Content</div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="top">Top content</div>
    <div class="inner-cont">
      <div class="middle">Middle Content</div>
      <div class="right">Right Content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! However, I'm confused on how to keep the flex-items the same size, as I don't want them to change based on the content. How would I use flex-shrink and flex-basis?

Comment: As I explained in my answer, set `flex-shrink: 0` and  `flex-basis: 0`

Comment: I understand that, but if I say
`body {
    overflow:hidden;
}
`
and include a lot of text in each one, then only the left and top boxes show up. I want the proportions to stay the same and cut off the excess text.

Comment: You need to add `overflow:hidden;` to each element

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
body{display:table}
.row{display:table-row}
.cell{display:table-cell}
.floatLeft{float:left}
.box1{background-color:#f00;width:100px;height:400px}
.box2{background-color:#0f0;width:400px;height:100px}
.box3{background-color:#00f;width:200px;height:300px}
.box4{background-color:#f0f;width:200px;height:300px}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell box1"></div>
    <div class="cell">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell box2 "></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell box3 floatLeft"></div>
            <div class="cell box4 floatLeft"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```